# How to create a txt file by using a form in php

Tags: php

For a project I need to ensure that when creating a new recipe from a form that creates a text file containing this same recipe.
[My form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KurYw.png)

I work in PHP

Comment: What you really want to do is `json_encode` it, since you have multiple fields there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) alongside [fwrite()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to write the form's variables into a `.txt` file.

Notably, with [fwrite()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) you are able to use the `"w"` (Write) mode which will automatically create the file for you if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: How would you write multiple variables into a `.txt` file?

Comment: Something like the example on [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#:~:text=%20if%20writing%20twice%20to%20the%20file%20pointer%2C%20then%20the%20data%20will%20be%20appended%20to%20the%20end%20of%20the%20file%20content%3A%20) part of the manual for fwrite() is what I had in mind. Would this not be sufficient?

Comment: `fwrite(...what here...)` is what I'm asking. You can't just put `$_POST` there right, because `fwrite(resource $stream, string $data, ...`)?